# How to tell if asynchronous JavaScript function for Chrome Extension fails?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to learn how to code Google Chrome extensions and I keep seeing that they use asynchronous JavaScript functions, [as such](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage):

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    message('Settings saved');
});
```

The function above calls a completion method upon successful result, which is good.

But what I'm curious to know is how to tell if this asynchronous function fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more or less uniform mechanism for Chrome APIs is to set [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError). It's usually indicated in the docs that it will be set if something goes wrong.

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
        // Notify that we saved.
        message('Settings saved');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I guess that "closure" function for the `chrome.storage.sync.set` method will be called in any case, right?

Comment: yes always gets called. the storage api docs also say to use the method above

Comment: @c00000fd There is one exceptional case when the `chrome.storage.sync.set` callback is *not* called. That is when it is called from a content script whose extension runtime has been reloaded; either due to an extension update/reload or by an explicit call to [`chrome.runtime.reload`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-reload). At that point every Chrome extension API that is implemented in native code doesn't respond at all.

Comment: One follow-up question guys. Is there any way to distinguish between a situation when quota was exceeded vs. any other error?